# The Derivative of a General Linear Map

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

This question is somewhat abstract compared to the things we've discussed in class, so I'm just making sure I've got the right idea. I'd appreciate any help/suggestions; I'm pretty sure I've got the right answer, but I may be totally incorrect in what I think the question is asking.

The question is:
Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is a linear map. What is the derivative of $f$?

My answer is: Let $f: A \subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a linear map where $A$ is an open set. Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. From the def. of a linear map, we know that $f(\alpha x) = \alpha f(x)$ and $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$. Thus, to be a linear map, no element in the image of $f$ can contain the product of elements in the domain of $f$ (otherwise, $f(x_1,x_2) = x_1x_2 \implies f(\alpha_1x_1,\alpha_2x_2) = \alpha^2x_1x_2 \ne \alpha f(x_1,x_2)$).

Given the above statement, all linear maps from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ must have the form...

$f(x_1,...,x_n) =$ $\begin{pmatrix} 
a_{1,1} x_1 ~ + ...+ ~ a_{1,n} x_n \\
\vdots \\
a_{m,1}x_1 ~ + ... + ~ a_{m,n} x_n
\end{pmatrix}$

Where $a_{i,j}$ is the coefficient of the $x_{j}$ term in the $i^{th}$ row. The derivative of this function is the matrix of partial derivatives of $f(x_1,...,x_n)$. Note, though, that the partial derivative of any row with respect to $x_i$ is just the coefficient of the $x_i$ term (since no other term in the row depends on $x_i$, thus their partial derivatives are zero). So our matrix of partial derivatives becomes:

$\frac{df}{dx} = \begin{pmatrix} 
a_{1,1} & ... & a_{1,n} \\
\vdots & \ddots\\
a_{m,1} & ... & a_{m,n}
\end{pmatrix}$

(That is, the matrix of coefficients where the $i^{th}$ column contains the $m$ coefficients of each $x_i$ term).

Can anyone verify whether or not a) This is actually what the question is looking for (I think the simplicity is making me skeptical) and b) Whether or not I've the correct answer if it is, in fact, what the question is looking for?

Comment: Another viewpoint is to think in terms of the approximation $f(x + \Delta x) \approx f(x) + f'(x) \Delta x$ (eq. 1), which is essentially the definition of $f'(x)$.  If $f(x) = A x$ for all $x$, then $f(x + \Delta x) = f(x) + A \Delta x$ (eq. 2).  Comparing equations 1 and 2, we see that $f'(x) = A$.

Comment: I dig that approach (it's also easier to write). This is a similar idea to the answer below, too. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. Also, you can verify that
$$
f(x+h) = f(x) + \frac{df}{dx} h
$$
which is a key property of the derivative that is used in many branches of applied mathematics.